# close() closes input streams permanently

Tags: java, io

I am trying to make a simple method `readIn()` that reads something in from `System.in`. (Can't use Console because `System.console()` returns null when I run in Eclipse). The idea is to call `readIn` as needed, like this

```
 classs Foo{
     public static void(String[] arg){

         String first = readIn("First, please");
         System.out.println(first);

         String second = readIn("Second, please");
         System.out.println(second);
     }
 }
```

Here is the simplest form of `readIn()`:

```
 static String readIn(String prompt){

     System.out.println(prompt + ": ");
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     String line = br.readLine();
     br.close();   // PROBLEM STATEMENT
     return line;

 }
```

If I omit the `br.close()` statement it works fine - I can call `readIn` repeatedly.  But if I close `br`, as I should, then only the first call works. Second call throws `IOException: Stream closed`. As expected, the same thing happens with try-with-resources in `readIn`:

```
 static String readIn(String prompt){

     System.out.println(prompt + ": ");
     String line;
     try(
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(System.in))  )
     {
         line = br.readLine();
     }

     return line;
 }
```

Same thing happens with `Scanner(System.in)` instead of `BufferedReader`. It does not happen when reading from files.

Which stream is closed if a new `BufferedReader` or `Scanner` is made in every call to `readIn`? Is this something about `close(`) closing the "underlying Readable/Closeable" (System.in)?  Can it be reopened?  Trying to understand, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it closes the underlying resource. This is clearly stated in the Javadoc. You should not keep creating and closing BufferedReaders or Scanners per read: you should use the same one for the life of the underlying resource.

Comment: OK.  And the life of the underlying System.in resource is what?  Same as the run of the JVM?

Comment: It doesn't close itself spontaneously, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`br.close();` closes also system input stream `System.in`, so you can't use it unless you restart JVM.
You can use the same `BufferedReader` instance for all required input from `System.in`

Don't be shy also to mix calls:

```
System.out.println
br.readLine();
```

They are related to different streams, so there shouldn't be any issues.